# Chrome not reachable, failing randomly for set of test cases

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, exception, webdriver

Please help me out of this, i have wasted the time like hell on this.

I have a test suite of 6 test cases, so when i run them, sometimes 3 got failed, other time some random numbers, the reason for all the failures is same "chrome not reachable"

I don't know how to fix this issue. I am getting the following error randomly for the failures.

> ERROR: test_addDevice (**main**.BluewaveTestClass)
>   --- New Device Planning ---
>   ---------------------------------------------------------------------- Traceback (most recent call last):   File "tc_ui.py", line 35, in
>   setUp
>       self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(pathChromedriver)   File "C:\Users\prateek.rajendra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium-3.0.2-py3.6.egg\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py",
>   line 69, in **init**
>       desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)   File "C:\Users\prateek.rajendra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium-3.0.2-py3.6.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
>   line 92, in **init**
>       self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)   File "C:\Users\prateek.rajendra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium-3.0.2-py3.6.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
>   line 179, in start_session
>       response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, capabilities)   File "C:\Users\prateek.rajendra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium-3.0.2-py3.6.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
>   line 236, in execute
>       self.error_handler.check_response(response)   File "C:\Users\prateek.rajendra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium-3.0.2-py3.6.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py",
>   line 192, in check_response
>       raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: chrome not
>   reachable   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.29.461591
>   (62ebf098771772160f391d75e589dc567915b233),platform=Windows NT
>   6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)

Comment: @PrateekJ Which version of Python are you using?

Comment: 3.6 is the python version

Comment: Can you consider showing us some of your work/code please? Thanks

Comment: from chromedriver.log

Comment: [2.046][DEBUG]: DevTools request: http://localhost:12420/json/version
[4.082][DEBUG]: DevTools request failed
[4.143][DEBUG]: DevTools request: http://localhost:12420/json/version
[4.347][DEBUG]: DevTools request failed
[4.408][DEBUG]: DevTools request: http://localhost:12420/json/version
[6.156][DEBUG]: DevTools request failed